# ¿Cómo busco en una consulta de sql un elemento que tenga una comilla simple en su interior?

Tags: c#, sql

Actualmente quiero hacer una consulta muy sencilla donde busco mediante el nombre el elemento de la fecha pero al momento de querer hacer la consulta en c# me retorna lo siguiente:

```
select top 1 FechaInicioComprometidaOriginal from Proyectosv2 where Nombre='Sellados de CFDI's '
```

Esto se debe a que el nombre viene en mi excel como `'Sellados de CFDI's` y confunde las comillas simples cuando quiero hacer la consulta, como se realizaría dicha consulta para que esa comilla extra no afecte.

Comment: Solo pon dos veces la comilla simple SELECT top 1 FechaInicioComprometidaOriginal from Proyectosv2 where Nombre='Sellados de CFDI''s'

Comment: @TheVicShow si yo hago eso funciona pero cuando viene el formato normal sin ninguna comilla extra como por ejemplo  " select top 1 FechaInicioComprometidaOriginal,nombre from Proyectosv2 where Nombre='96893 Calibración Escenarios E16 al E20''' " y le pongo las comillas simples la consulta ya no funcionaria para ese elemento y sin embargo existe asi que necesito que funcione para ambas situaciones

Comment: Podrías escapar la comilla con \' por ejemplo Nombre='Sellados de CFDI\'s' esto tal vez podría funcionarte

Comment: Eso sucede porque estás armando la consulta en C#. Usa parámetros para que no te suceda.

Answer (score 3):

Recomiendo que utilices `SIEMPRE PARAMETROS` , concatenar en un string los valores es una pésima idea (ya que es susceptible a Inyección SQL y es un grave fallo de seguridad).

```
string filtro = "Sellados de CFDI's";

DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))  
{  
    string query = @"select top 1 FechaInicioComprometidaOriginal 
                    from Proyectosv2 
                    where Nombre= @nombre";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", filtro);  

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);    
    da.Fill(dt);  
}
```

Si lo haces de esta forma no tendras ningún problema con los caracteres especiales.

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de editar tu respuesta y mencionar porqué es es una pésima idea usar cadenas concatenadas

Comment: @Phi genial, es bueno dejar claro porque no debe concatenar los valores

Comment: definitivamente son grandes :D